# What can I use to adequately insulate round rigid metal ducts?

Tags: hvac, insulation, ducts

I'm installing properly sealed round metal ducts in my unconditioned attic for heating and cooling. I've probably got 100' total of 6" duct to cover.  I'm trying to achieve an R-8 insulation value, but the big box stores only sell R-6 Frost King wraps.  Can I use un-faced insulation batts (that you use in the attic), and then wrap a foil layer around it? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need R-8?  Why must you buy from a big box store?

Comment: I have found it easier and cheaper to actually wrap the entire round duct in an insulated flex duct and just "specially" wrap the points where it branches off.

Comment: @Tester101 R-8 seems to be recommended for energy efficiency in unconditioned spaces.  Do you recommend otherwise?  Big box isn't a requirement, just the place I looked first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Owens Corning's](http://www.owenscorning.com/) 3" Type 75 [SOFTR® Duct Wrap FRK](http://insulation.owenscorning.com/homeowners/renovation/products/softr-duct-wrap-frk/), touts and installed R-value of 8.3.

If it's not in-stock at your local big box store, they should be able to order it for you.

[image]

<sup><sub>*I am in no way affiliated with Owens Corning, and do not recommend or endorse the use of any of their products or services.*</sub></sup>